# IO Exception "System cannot find the file specified" in WordCount Mapreduce program

Tags: java, mapreduce, ioexception

I am fairly new to Map/Reduce and Hadoop. I am trying to write a wordccount mapreduce program and I am running it locally using eclipse. I have specified the path of the input file and also the output directory. When I am compiling the program it throws an IO Exception "The system cannot find the file specified."

My code look like this

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;

public class WordCount {
public static class Wordcountmapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word=new Text();
    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output,
            Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

        String line = value.toString();
        System.out.println("Line " + line);
        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(line,",");

        while(token.hasMoreTokens())

        {
            word.set(token.nextToken());
            output.collect(word, one);
            System.out.println("hii  " + word + " " + one);
        }   
    }   
}
public static class wordcountreducer extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> value,
            OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {
        int sum = 0 ;
        System.out.println("Inside Reducer" + value.hasNext());
        System.out.println("Key = " + key );
        while(value.hasNext()) {
            sum += value.next().get();
        }
        output.collect(key,new IntWritable(sum));
        System.out.println(key + " " + sum);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    conf.setMapperClass(Wordcountmapper.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(wordcountreducer.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path("C:\\WordCount\\wordcount.txt"));
    String outputfile = "C:\\WordCount\\Output\\a.txt";
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(outputfile));
    JobClient.runJob(conf);
}
}
```

Am I missing something here? I am using Eclipse Juno with hadoop plugin installed for running map reduce programs.

The error being thrown is as follows

```
15/01/22 17:54:43 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.key.class
15/01/22 17:54:43 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.value.class
15/01/22 17:54:43 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
15/01/22 17:54:43 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/01/22 17:54:43 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
15/01/22 17:54:43 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
15/01/22 17:54:43 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
15/01/22 17:54:43 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
15/01/22 17:54:43 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
15/01/22 17:54:43 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.queue.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.queuename
15/01/22 17:54:43 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:Soorya S (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "chmod": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "chmod": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:471)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:384)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:658)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:641)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:639)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:277)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:969)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:963)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:573)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1502)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:963)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:937)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1375)
    at com.ibm.hadoop.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:92)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:41)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:464)
    ... 23 more
getting access token
  [getToken] got user access token

getting primary group
  [getPrimaryGroup] Got TokenPrimaryGroup info
  [getPrimaryGroup] primaryGroup: S-1-5-21-184784153-2138975554-913327727-513
getting supplementary groups
  [getGroups] Got TokenGroups info
  [getGroups] group 0: S-1-5-21-184784153-2138975554-913327727-513
  [getGroups] group 1: S-1-1-0
  [getGroups] group 2: S-1-5-114
  [getGroups] group 3: S-1-5-32-544
  [getGroups] group 4: S-1-5-32-545
  [getGroups] group 5: S-1-5-4
  [getGroups] group 6: S-1-2-1
  [getGroups] group 7: S-1-5-11
  [getGroups] group 8: S-1-5-15
  [getGroups] group 9: S-1-5-113
  [getGroups] group 10: S-1-5-5-0-576278
  [getGroups] group 11: S-1-2-0
  [getGroups] group 12: S-1-5-64-10
  [getGroups] group 13:S-1-16-8192
```

Comment: Where is the error being thrown?

Comment: I have added the error being thrown in eclipse console.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (I assume You are using windows). It happens because system path variable pointing to 'chmod' executable needs to be set. You can follow steps as described here [running hadoop on window-7 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388849/running-hadoop-on-window-7-64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

I Had same issue the following exception as Hadoop makes system call to unix tool chmod :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "chmod": CreateProcess error=2,
The system cannot find the file specified :
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:201)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:376)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:445)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.execCommand(RawLocalFileSystem.java:543)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:535)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:336)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:400)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:610)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:591)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile$Writer.<init>(HFile.java:306)
        at org.expasy.jpl.io.util.JPLHMapSerializer.init(JPLHMapSerializer.java:125)
```

can you please try using bellow

Fixing Dependence Bug
The solution is to install cygwin in your windows system or install a subset of it as only chmod and its dlls   are needed. We will provide, in the following, a solution for the second alternative:

First Step: Get "chmod" Resources
Here are the archives for different Windows architectures:

Windows 32-bit - contains chmod.exe, cygwin1.dll, cygiconv-2.dll, cygintl-8.dll and cyggcc_s-1.dll
Windows 64-bit - not yet available
Second Step: Set your Path in Windows
Do not forget to set your PATH variable for chmod in Windows else chmod will not be found!!

First right-click on your My Computer icon on your Desktop and click on Properties. Alternatively you could just press the Windows Key+Pause Break Key
Then in the new window that opened, click on the Advanced tab
Click on Environment Variables
In System Variables, edit or create the PATH variable and enter the path name to cygwin-chmod directory

Answer (score 0):

install cygwin and add it to your path environment

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error :Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "chmod" with a java hadoop program, try to Run eclipse as an administrator. For me has worked.